# SSL handshake randomly failing - due to insecure content?

Tags: ssl

I purchased an SSL via my hosting providers for a client and from time to time the site is going down due to the SSL. Its saying the page is not secure.

I have contacted my hosting providers who have been very helpful as it is an intermittent problem so they cant debug it.

Im being left in the dark a bit here, but the only thing I can see is that there are some insecure items on the homepage causing a broken padlock.

Is it possible that this can cause a full SSL failure or could contribute to the problem in any way?

Thanks

Comment: You're loading insecure content ...

Comment: I didnt think that would cause a total failure though? Just a broken padlock? Thats my main question really

Comment: Yes, it does. If you're loading a script over plain http, it can be tainted and thus renders the complete DOM insecure because that script could potentially insert all kind of bad things in to your html page.

Comment: Also check that whoever installed it also installed the CA Root Bundle (if applicable). This can cause complete failure in some browser versions/os if not installed whilst being ok in others.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the CA Root Bundle was installed alright.